# Consumption cost from wireless sensor

Tags: energy, power-consumption, processing

I want to get an approximate energy model for wireless sensors when a given task is executed. I know that we can compute the energy consumption from a PC based on the time performing a task. For instance, a 2.2 GHz pentium 4 with a 400 MHz FSB has a typical Vcc of 1.3725 Volts and Icc of 47.9 Amps which is (1.3725*47.9=) 65.74 watts which a process taking 0.00454278s will consume 65.74 watts * 0.00454278s = 0.305 watt seconds (or joules). How can I do the same operation for wireless sensor? For instance, this one from [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/quark-c1000-datasheet.pdf) . How can I get the energy consumed from that node from a task which took 1.5 seconds to be executed?

Which other elements should be considered to get a more realistic energy model? In overall, I want to know how much an operation consumes in-node for WSN.

Comment: Look at the datasheet.

Comment: @RDrast I took a look. I cannot see Icc in Amps. which value should I get for Vcc 1.8, 2.6 or 3.3?